# Trying to open a Dialog Menu with an Options Menu Item

Tags: android, list, menu, dialog, alert

I am trying to open an Alert Dialog with a list in it for the user to select some options, but the dialog will be opened from an options menu item. I have included the code for the Options Item and the dialog menu.

```
public void OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case SECTION:
            showDialogMenu();
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    showDialogMenu();
                    Log.d("Dialog used.","here");
                }
            }; break;
        }
    }


public void showDialogMenu(){
    Log.d("showDialogMenu()", "Method was called.");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.dialogueTitle);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Melee", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=0;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Pistols", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=27;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Shotguns", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=38;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Rifles", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=43;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sub-Machine Guns", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=58;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Light Machine Guns", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=68;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sniper Rifles", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            num=72;
            whichImage(num);
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

I made sure to have the show() method for the dialog, i thought that was the problem before, but when the menu item is clicked, nothing comes up. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy fella...no one thinks you're stupid. I don't know what `SECTION` is but you should change that to whatever you gave the id in your menu xml

```
<item android:id="MyItem"
```

then in your `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
public void OnOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.MyItem:
        showDialogMenu();
        break;
```

move your `showDialog()` method outside of here so it can be resuable.

```
public void showDialogMenu(){
                Log.d("Dialog used.","here");
            }
```

Its fine to use a `switch/case` here because chances are that you will want to add more items at some point

That should help your current problem. But you will want to check into using a [MultiChoice Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) for what you are doing